# How to create an a virtual hostname or a simple url for appmaker

Tags: google-app-maker

The URL for app-maker is always pretty complicated and is not human readable... 
Is there a way to configure a host name or simplify the URL, in order to have the users being able to remember it?

for example:

```
myapp.mydomain.com
```

or at least:
`scripts.google.com/myapp_prod` or similar?

Until now I wasn't able to find out a way to have a fixed URL for the prod deployment for example.

Comment: The only solution would be to put the app in an iframe and then have the iframe embeded in a web page. Unfortunately the app itself cannot have a different URL at this time.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that for accessing purposes only and if you have some kind of hosting, a permanent redirect will do the trick. Alternatively, you can use some javascript to redirect to the app url whenever the home page is loaded.

```
window.open(appurl, "_top");
```

But other than that, the comment provided by Markus Malessa is the most correct one.